# I can ping a network computer but not access it

Tags: networking

I am able to ping a computer in the network but not able to access the share folder in the computer.

Answer (score 2):

ICMP/Ping and shared drives have different access rules and settings on a host.  By testing ICMP/Ping and getting a response from the host, you're only verifying the computer is responding to network calls (through the ICMP protocol).  Now check your shared folder settings since these might not be setup properly.  You should always include what Operating System when you have the question, also include your sharing method, as there are many methods of sharing folders.

Ah, Windows 2003...

Test the share from the same server \Name and see if this opens properly, also double check your folder share privileges to the user account trying to access the resource (shared folder).  Another thing to try would be to check the server event logs and see if there are any errors pertaining to sharing or the server service.

Comment: We are using Widows 2003. Sharing is normal windows share with the foldername as the share name. ie sharing a folder in one system by right clicking the folder and giving a name.
This was workng fine till today. Now while I access the other computer using \\Name , getting an error ;- "\\System110 is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. The network is not present or not started.

I can ping the computer by IP address, but not able to access.

Answer (score 1):

Also try using the command line to force specific credentials:

```
net use \\server\share /username:username
```

It should prompt you for the password.

Answer (score 1):

One step up from PING is to see if you can get to the box via NetBIOS (over TCP/IP). My steps usually are:

1. ping
2. `nbtstat -A serverIP` - if fail, check 135/139/445 (TCP) and 137/139 (UDP) open
3. `nbtstat -a servername` - if fail, check DNS/WINS is ok
4. `net view \\servername`

PortQueryUI can be used to check ports also. If ports are open, perhaps "can't access it" is really a security thing; check AD account ok, security messages in event logs.

Answer (score 0):

you probably turned on a firewall rule by mistake... or when u said \name it asked you password and you closed the window that asks you the password.. if so, only problem you have is to get that window back (log out, and log in and do \name) or check your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can try open shared folder using ip address instead of computer name,

\\IP_Aadres\SherdFolder

Where is Ip_adress of inforamt like 192.186.0.1

Answer (score 0):

ideally you want to disable simple file sharing

```
Explorer > tools > folder options > View
```

and right down the bottom untick the use simple file sharing

this will give you more control.

then go to the firewall and tick allow file and printer sharing
 and voila fixed